# IntelliJ decompile class with all synthetic methods

Tags: intellij-idea, compiler-optimization, decompiler, java-bridge-method, java-synthetic-methods

I am using IntelliJ with built in decompiler.
I would like to decompile a .class file and see all methods which are created by java compiler (for instance synthetic bridge methods [bridge methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html)). Is there possibility to do that in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible at the moment, please [vote for this feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-128285).

Comment: That is a pity. I have added my vote. So no other plugin which would do that?

Comment: @fascynacja you can use Fernflower decompiler from the command line or configure an external tool for that. It's the [same engine](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/plugins/java-decompiler/engine/readme.txt) that is used in IDEA, it has an option to show bridge methods.